# Why are the developer tools closing in Chromium Selenium-driven?

Tags: selenium, clojure, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to debug an issue with my tests and I'd like to open the developer tools in Chromium. Chromium is being scripted by Selenium from Clojure (that is, Java) and for some r as on, after I open the developer tools, they get closed in less than a second.

Any ideas what's going on here or how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any selenium methods  (find element, click, etc.) on the page when the tools close?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, according to Google.

Why is this happening and how to fix it you can read here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing